# Can I perform Wudu during bathing, while in nude?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, wudu, sahih-bukhari

I usually take bath in the nude. While in nude, can I perform all the steps of wudu without washing the legs, then, perform the bathing and while bathing is complete and I'm dressed, can I then just wash my legs to complete the wudu?

Will it be sahih?

Please provide some authentic reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a shower/bath, it can include Wudu. If the shower was to clean yourself after sex or period, then the intention (Niah) is inclusive. If that isn't the case and the shower is just to clean yourself, you should make the intention before taking a shower that it includes Wudu.

[Fatwa Source](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=8365)

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His Family and Companions

Yes you can perform Wudhu during Bathing performing all of the steps with making an intention for wudhu but it is not allowed to perform wudhu in such a way that after you have performed ghusl then you do some other stuff and now you are continuing your wudhu this should be avoided you could wash your feet in the end of ghusl and here are the references which you have asked for

> It was narrated from 'Aishah that when the Prophet (ﷺ) performed Ghusl
>   from Janabah he would start by washing his hands, then he would
>   perform Wudu' as for prayer, then he would dip his fingers in the
>   water, then run them through his hair, then he would pour water over
>   his head three times, then he would pour water over his entire
>   body.([Sunan An Nasai](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1002490))

Aishah narrated:

> "The Prophet would not perform Wudu after the Ghusl."([Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/107))

Narrated Hisham bin `Urwa: (on the authority of his father)`Aisha

> said, "Whenever Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) took the bath of Janaba, he
>   cleaned his hands and performed ablution like that for prayer and then
>   took a bath and rubbed his hair, till he felt that the whole skin of
>   the head had become wet, then he would pour water thrice and wash the
>   rest of the body." `Aisha further said, "I and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   used to take a bath from a single water container, from which we took
>   water simultaneously."([Sahih Bukhari](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/5/25))

Allah Swt and his Messenger knows best.